# Sending file to unknown client address through socket?

Tags: java, sockets, fileoutputstream

Essentially what I'm trying to do is have a client (with an unknown IP) connect via socket to a server, and have the server send a `BufferedImage` back to the client every `x` seconds.

I understand how this can be done with a known client IP, but not with an unknown. A simple example would be awesome, thanks.

Example with known IP:

```
BufferedImage scr = getImage();
Socket sock = new Socket(ip, 123456); //unknown IP
byte[] mybytearray = new byte[1024];
InputStream is = sock.getInputStream();
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(scr);
BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(fos);
int bytesRead = is.read(mybytearray, 0, mybytearray.length);
bos.write(mybytearray, 0, bytesRead);
bos.close();
sock.close();
```

Also, if anyone could show me where I could loop it to keep sending the file, that would be awesome.

Comment: The server IP must be known to connect. After the client connects to the known server IP you can transmit the information to the client.

Comment: 1. If you don't know the IP, you cannot address the packets. 2. Why don't you know the IP once the client connects to the server?

Comment: The server IP is known. The client whom is connecting is not.

Comment: @user3613821 I think you are mistaken how the whole server client works. The server doesn't know about the client until the client attempts to connect. It is the client that is in knowledge of where it needs to connect to and the server that is listening for connections.

Comment: Can you show how would you do it with known client address? Maybe only a minor change is necessary.

Comment: @Banthar Added to the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I whipped up some sample server client connection. Basically you just define your server to use your localhost then port forward or open the server port depending on what your network configuration is. Thers lots of tutorials about that online. On your client you need to either know your external or internal IP address depending on where your connecting from.

This sample just uses your localhost and sends a file from your harddrive, but I wrote it specifically with the intended use of adding in any `InputStream` or `OutputStream` so you can adapt this to reading or writing an image. Most servers you will just bind your ip address to 127.0.0.1. When connection to the server outside your local network you will need to find your external IP address. You can find this on websites like [whatsmyip.org](http://www.whatsmyip.org/).

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.InetSocketAddress;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;


public class SendFileExample {
    public static void main(String [] args) throws IOException {
        System.out.print("Type 's' for server or 'c' for client: ");

        char c = (char) System.in.read();
        if(Character.toLowerCase(c) == 's') {
            createServer();
        } else if(Character.toLowerCase(c) == 'c') {
            createClient();
        }
    }

    public static void createServer() throws IOException {
        // create a server to listen on port 12345
        ServerSocket socket = new ServerSocket(12345, 0, InetAddress.getByName("127.0.0.1"));
        System.out.println("Server started on " + socket.getInetAddress().getHostAddress() + ":" + socket.getLocalPort() + ",\nWaiting for client to connect.");
        Socket clientConnection = socket.accept();
        System.out.println("Client accepted from "+clientConnection.getInetAddress().getHostAddress()+", sending file");
        pipeStreams(new FileInputStream(new File("c:\\from.txt")), clientConnection.getOutputStream(), 1024);
        System.out.println("File sent, closing out connection");
        clientConnection.close();
        socket.close();
    }

    public static void createClient() throws IOException {
        System.out.println("Connecting to server.");
        Socket socket = new Socket();
        // connect to an address, this is the server address (which you have to know)
        socket.connect(new InetSocketAddress(InetAddress.getByName("127.0.0.1"), 12345));
        // read all bytes from the socket
        System.out.println("Success, retreiving file.");
        pipeStreams(socket.getInputStream(), new FileOutputStream(new File("c:\\to.txt")), 1024);
        System.out.println("Done, file sent. Closing connection");
        socket.close();
    }


    /**
     * writes all bytes from inputStream to outputStream
     * @param source
     * @param out
     * @throws IOException
     */
    public static void pipeStreams(java.io.InputStream source, java.io.OutputStream destination, int bufferSize) throws IOException {

        // 16kb buffer
        byte [] buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
        int read = 0;
        while((read=source.read(buffer)) != -1) {
            destination.write(buffer, 0, read);
        }
        destination.flush();
        destination.close();
        source.close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the cleanest way to achieve this would be to have the client connect every x seconds to the server, and pull the image from the socket's stream.

If you want the server to have the initiative, have the client connect to the server, and then keep the socket open to send images every x second. This means that the client must be ready to read the images as they come. It also means that the length of an image must be sent before it's content, since the image is not terminated by the end of the stream.